# ANTLR StringTemplate infinite loop while rendering the template

Tags: antlr, stringtemplate

I am using antlr-3.4-complete.jar which i believe is using StringTemplate version 3.2.1

I have the following productions in the tree grammar

```
functionCall 
  : ^(FUNCCALL NCName pr+=params*) ->template(n={$NCName.text},p={$pr})"<n> <p>"
```

The above StringTemplate runs correctly and is generating correct output.

I have another production in the same grammar which is very similar to the production above

```
step  
  :  axisSpecifier nodeTest pred+=predicate* 
       ->template(a={$axisSpecifier.st},n={$nodeTest.st},pc={$pred})"<a> <n> <pc>"
  ;
```

But when i print the template it goes in infinite recursion, the stack is as below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
    at org.antlr.stringtemplate.StringTemplate.getAttributeRenderer(StringTemplate.java:1080)
```

The generated code for the above production is as below

```
retval.st = new StringTemplate(templateLib, "<a> <n> <pc>",new STAttrMap().put("a", (axisSpecifier14!=null?axisSpecifier14.st:null)).put("n", (nodeTest15!=null?nodeTest15.st:null)).put("pc", list_pred));
```

The `list_pred` is the list containing the StringTemplates for `predicate*`.
When i debug the code i find that just before the above line, the individual StringTemplates are fine. By being fine i mean i can read the value in the debugger as the String value. But as soon as the above line is executed, i.e. `new StringTemplate` is done, the `toString()` method starts to fail. not only for the new StringTemplate but also for the  StringTemplate `list_pred`

I am unable to go forward with my work, as i dont think this is a problem with my grammar, as another production with same structure is working fine.

Can this error occur because of the parameter names i have chosen?

`template(a={$axisSpecifier.st},n={$nodeTest.st},pc={$pred})"<a> <n> <pc>"`

if i change the names from `a`,`n`,`pc` to something else will it help? as i see i have used the same names other places in the grammar also.

I suspect the method

`StringTemplate.breakTemplateIntoChunks()` might be the reason here? as this method will parse the template.

Can someone familiar with StringTemplate internals help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Regards,
Vimal

**UPDATE:**
This is the output from my AST construction, this also forms the input for treeGrammar. `(VARREF abc) / (STEPS (STEP child x (PRED (< (STEPS (STEP child price)) 10)))) END`

The `PRED` is the predicate which is also an `Expr`

My Tree Grammars with ST is as follows.

```
expr  
   :  ^('<' e1=expr e2=expr) ->template(e11={$e1.st},e21={$e2.st})"\< <e11> <e21>"  
   | mainexpr -> template(mnexpr={$mainexpr.st})"<mnexpr>"  
   ;  

mainexpr  
scope  
{  
  boolean isRLP ;  
} :   
    filterExpr ('/' {$mainexpr::isRLP = true;} relativeLocationPath)?   
     -> {$mainexpr::isRLP}? template(filtr={$filterExpr.st},rlp=  {$relativeLocationPath.st})"<filtr> <rlp>"  
     -> template(filtr={$filterExpr.st})"<filtr>"  
  | relativeLocationPath -> template(rlp={$relativeLocationPath.st})"<rlp>"  
  ;  

relativeLocationPath : ^(STEPS st+=steps+) -> template(stps={$st})"<stps>";  

steps  
  :   ^(STEP step) ->template(stp={$step.st})"<stp>"    
  ;  
step   
  :  axisSpecifier nodeTest (pred+=predicate)*  
           ->template(axs={$axisSpecifier.st},ndtst={$nodeTest.st},stppred={$pred})"<axs> <ndtst> <stppred>"  
  ;  

predicate  
  : ^(PRED expr) ->template(predexp={$expr.st})"<predexp>"  
  ;
```

Output of LintMode:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: infinite recursion to <anonymous([])@76> referenced in <anonymous([])@69>; stack trace:  
<anonymous([])@76>, attributes=[predexp=<anonymous()@75>], references=[predexp, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@69>, attributes=[ndtst=<anonymous()@68>, stppred, axs=<anonymous()@67>], references=[axs, ndtst, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@70>, attributes=[stp=<anonymous()@69>], references=[stp, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@71>, attributes=[stps=List[..<anonymous()@70>..]], references=[stps, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@72>, attributes=[rlp=<anonymous()@71>], references=[rlp, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@73>, attributes=[mnexpr=<anonymous()@72>], references=[mnexpr, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@75>, attributes=[e21=<anonymous()@74>, e11=<anonymous()@73>],   references=[e11, stppred]>  
<anonymous([])@76> (start of recursive cycle)
```

Comment: Doesn't ANTLR 3.4 use StringTemplate v4? You might want to ask your question on the [StringTemplate mailing-list](http://www.antlr.org/mailman/listinfo/stringtemplate-interest): Terence roams SO from time to time, but there aren't a lot of *StringTemplaters* around here (yet!) :) Good luck!

Comment: @BartKiers, thansk for your response. I print the value of variable `StringTemplate.VERSION` and i get 3.2.1 so i say it uses 3.2.1. Also the source i downloaded for 3.2.1 is able to match with code when i debug.

Comment: @BartKiers the problem is somewhere in StringTemplate.toString() and the trouble with debugging this method is that when i am trying to locate the source of error, whenever i check the value of any StringTemplate, the debugger internally calls the `toString()` before i can complete my stepping of toString() :)

Comment: Ah, I quickly looked in the 3.4 JAR and saw a `org/stringtemplate/v4` path, but `StringTemplate.VERSION` seems pretty conclusive :). I'm not able to help: not really familiar with ST...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANTLR v3.4 uses ST v4 for its cogeneration, but for backward compatibility, the generated code uses ST v3.2.1.

You have embedded a template within itself. Turn on lint mode to find the infinite cycle in the template nesting graph.

Comment: Hi Terr, thanks a lot Sir, for taking time to answer. But my StringTemplates are following the same patterns as my CombinedGrammar and TreeGrammar. The top level is `Expr` which down the line contains a `Predicate` which itself can be an `Expr`. CombinedGrammar, TreeGrammar can support this. I can walk the tree with the TreeGrammar. But when i introduce StringTemplates i get this error. Yes my ST for `Predicate` invokes ST for `Expr`. I used the lint mode and got the same in the lint output. Does this mean ST can't support this. OR may be i should not think of ST as a grammar...

Comment: Hi, I have added my TreeGrammar with the ST in the main question above. Can you please look at it and suggest any change. - Thanks

Comment: is it possible that since i am using a anonymous templates ('lambda' generated templates) i am getting this error? I will try with 'named' templates and let you know the result.

Comment: Hi Terr, It is working fine now. i moved the ST definitions from TreeGrammar to a separate stg file and invoked those STs from the TreeGrammar and everything works as of now :) Thanks a Lot for following my tweet and taking time to answer this.